# Як перекласти "dimmable"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, прикметники, словотворення

> Dimmable:
>
> Able to be dimmed; able to have illumination decreased in brightness.

Це оствітлювальні прилади (лампочки) що можуть зменшувати яскравість.
В магазинах використовують російський термін *диммируемая* абож просто пишуть англійською - *dimmable LED lamp.*

Гугл-перекладач пропонує варіанти *затемнений* чи *дросельний* - жоден не є вірним. Прямі кальки з російської чи англійської звучать неприродно.

Comment: У Вікіпедії «dimmer» називають «регулятором освітленості», «світлорегулятором», «пристроєм зниження/збільшення освітлення»; на e2u — «притемнювачем», «затемнювачем», «реґулятором освітлення». Відповідно, може, «зі здатністю затемнення / зі здатністю зниження яскравості»?

Comment: тільки з "функцією", а не "зі здатністю"

Comment: Додав теґ «словотворення», тому що запитання передбачає, в основному, утворення нового слова. Це підтверджує також і одна з наявних відповідей.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Існує чудова стаття - [Процесові прикметники в науковій мові](https://r2u.org.ua/node/162), якою варто послуговуватись при потребі утворити таких прикметників.

Тут нам потрібне слово, яке позначає здатність бути підданим дії від слова *затемн-юва-ти*.

> Коли ж і надалі ми не можемо утворити прикметника (точніше, виходить щось немилозвучне та кострубате, як-от: *вгамувати — *вгамний, порівняти — *порівнний, знищити — *знищний*), тоді прикметник можна утворити таким чином: а) від твірної дієслівної основи з суфіксом **-ува-** відтяти кінцевий голосний **а**, відновити в усіченому суфіксі первинний голосний **о** та додати суфікса **-н-**: *вгам-ува-ти* ( давніше вгамовати - *вгам-ов-ний*); ...

Отже, виходить **затемновний**. Звучить незвично, прочитаймо ще один уривок:

> Попри те, що у бюлетенях 1930-их рр. слова із суфіксом **-ов**- (та
>   **-овн-**), особливо під наголосом, було оголошено «полонізмами» і фактично заборонено вживати, такі слова масово існують і постають у
>   науковій мові. ... Сучасну наукову літературу важко собі уявити без слів
>   типу *нехтовний, прогнозовний, інтеґровний, реґульовний, зліченний,
>   скінченний* тощо.

Answer (score 2):

Оскільки "прикручене" освітлення називають "приглушеним", то можна вжити "приглушуваний".

Так, це поки що not a word, але нема причин, чому б йому не бути.

Comment: Навіть словникове: «[приглушуваний](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryghlushuvanyj)».

Comment: @Sasha Ну, власне, зі "світильником" воно поки що не комбінувалося, а так слово є.